# Knowing cache behaviour for C program

Tags: c, caching

Is there any way to know the cache hit rate or some behaviour of the cache memory when I run my C program?

I'm trying to compare how the cache is acting with 2 different implementations of the function.

Comment: If you have a correctly working program code, you mitght ask at code review. As given, the question is OT for SO.

Comment: Note that the tools that support this are platform and/or compiler specific.  The answer(s) for Windows will be different from Linux, which will be different again from the answers for AIX, Mac OS X, HP-UX, Solaris, …

Comment: Why do you care? What should matter more is the overall performance of your program, or of a significantly large function inside it. The cache is part of the platform (actually, of the processor)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm doing some research for the university and that's one of the things I'm working on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, there are tools that let you do this, but as one would expect they are platform/architecture specific. They may also have compiler restriction:

1. [Cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html): Cache and branch-prediction profiler. This is probably the closest to what you are looking for. You can use it through `valgrind` (assuming a **Linux** kernel)

   `valgrind --tool=cachegrind your_program`

It has a few more options for fine-tuning. Have a look at the documentation. A typical dump/output in `Cachegrind` would look like (stripped from the website)

```
==31751== I   refs:      27,742,716
==31751== I1  misses:           276
==31751== LLi misses:           275
==31751== I1  miss rate:        0.0%
==31751== LLi miss rate:        0.0%
==31751== 
==31751== D   refs:      15,430,290  (10,955,517 rd + 4,474,773 wr)
==31751== D1  misses:        41,185  (    21,905 rd +    19,280 wr)
==31751== LLd misses:        23,085  (     3,987 rd +    19,098 wr)
==31751== D1  miss rate:        0.2% (       0.1%   +       0.4%)
==31751== LLd miss rate:        0.1% (       0.0%   +       0.4%)
==31751== 
==31751== LL misses:         23,360  (     4,262 rd +    19,098 wr)
==31751== LL miss rate:         0.0% (       0.0%   +       0.4%)
```

For **Windows** there is also the [WinCachegrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/)

2. [gem5](http://www.m5sim.org/Main_Page): A modular platform for computer-system architecture research. Works on **ARM**, **X86**, **Alpha**, **SPARC**. It also supports some specific GPU models. Not sure if it supports non-POSIX platforms.
3. [CACTI](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~rajeev/cacti6/): An integrated cache access time, cycle time, area, leakage, and dynamic power model for uniform and non-uniform cache architectures.
4. [MARSSx86](http://marss86.org/~marss86/index.php/Home): Micro-architectural and system simulator for x86-based systems.

Comment: Thank you very much @romeric!